# Putting the calling user-id into the header of a REST-API

Tags: rest, http-headers, query-string

I am exposing REST API's via an API Gateway so the requests go
Client => API Gateway => Back-end.

My back-end REST API's need to know about 2 users

**1: Target User (on some requests)**
the API needs this data for its action e.g.: *groups/{abc}/add-user* needs to know which user to add to a group

**2: Calling User (on every request):**
the API needs to check that this user is allowed to perform the action eg: only a group admin may add another user to the group.

I don't want other developers to get confused when looking \ adding to my API's so I want to create a convention. Is it a good idea to add the calling user ID as a header on every request?
eg: "user-context": "12345"

**Before everyone screams "INSECURE!!!!", I should add some info to put your minds at ease**

- The calling user is allowed to know their user-id. It's not a problem
- The target user is not identified by their real user-ID but by an obfuscated ID
- The calling-user-id is actually passed in a signed JWT to my API Gateway. The API-Gateway validates the JWT, takes the calling-user-id and adds it to the back-end request. What i'm really asking here is whether the API-Gateway should put the calling-user-id in the header (eg: "user context": "12345") or the query string /myapi/?calling-user-id=12345

I've tried both approaches and they both work. I'm wanting to know which approach makes the most sense to other developers.

Comment: Usually the 'calling user' is identified through the `Authorization` header.

Comment: I don't get why you think an user id is a secret. The secret is the private key you use to make the JWT and the password of the user. Even the username and email is not necessarily a secret, at least it is relative easy to guess.

Comment: The UserID of users other than the calling user would generally be considered sensitive information. I have the UserID in the JWT so thay

Comment: @Jonathan How is it sensitive?